# Rails Stimulus delete resource from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I am trying to implement a "delete" action via Stimulus in order to replace the boring JS validation windows with sweetalert2. I have the below code, which results in two errors:

1. While the resource (a book) indeed IS deleted, there is no redirect happening, i. e. I don't see any change (nor the notification that the book has been deleted etc)
2. I see an error in the JS console saying "DELETE http://127.0.0.1:3000/books 404 (Not Found)"; in the rails console, I see that after the book deletion request, there is indeed another deletion request fired to /books (which of course does not work).

I don't understand why there is an error, and I don't quite get what to do to redirect, i. e. to have the "destroy" method running properly?

Controller (excerpt):

```
  def destroy
    @book.destroy
    flash[:alert] = "Book removed"
    redirect_to books_path
  end
```

View (excerpt):

```
<%= button_to "delete_path", method: :delete, title: "Remove Book",
            form: { data: {
              turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?",
              controller: "sweetalert",
              action: 'click->sweetalert#confirm',
              "sweetalert-item-value": item_name,
              "sweetalert-url-value": url,
            } },
            class: "delete-icon nobutton" do %>
    <svg>......
```

Stimulus controller code:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import { getMetaValue } from "../helpers/index";

// Connects to data-controller="sweetalert"
export default class extends Controller {
  static values = {
    item: String,
    url: String,
  };

  confirm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const csrfToken = getMetaValue("csrf-token");

    Swal.fire({
      titleText: "Are you sure?",
      text: `You are about to delete "${this.itemValue}"`,
      icon: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#991c00",
      cancelButtonColor: "#407bbf",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        fetch(this.urlValue, {
          method: "DELETE",
          credentials: "same-origin",
          headers: {
            "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken,
          },
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `redirect_to books_path, status: :see_other`

Comment: thanks - that does the trick in terms of not sending another deletion request to /books, but the page still does not refresh (and neither is the notification "book removed" shown)?